# R igraph: Scaling node size

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I currently use following script to create a plot for betweenness centrality:

```
plot(g, 
     rescale = FALSE,
     edge.color= edge_color,
     edge.width=E(g)$Weight*0.5,
     vertex.size= degree(g)*0.5,
     main="Degree Centrality"
)
```

As you can see, I currently use a simple multiplier to adjust `vertex.size`. As some nodes are really big and some seem too small, I would like to set a range with a minimum and maximum size. Of course, that range should consider degree(g).

Is that somehow possible?

Note: Attempts with `scale (degree(g), 5, 15)` or similar did not work: "Error in symbols(x = coords[, 1], y = coords[, 2], bg = vertex.color,  : 
  invalid symbol parameter"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To rescale numbers, x, with a domain of (a,b) to a range of (c,d) you need to make a rescaling function like:

```
rescale = function(x,a,b,c,d){c + (x-a)/(b-a)*(d-c)}
```

So then if you have degree sizes from 0 to 200, and want your vertex sizes to range from 1 to 5 units, specify the vertex size with:

```
rescale(degree(g), 0, 200, 1, 5)
```

This is just a simple linear transformation - you might want something non-linear for better visuals.

You might find a `rescale` function in a package somewhere (like the `rescale` function in the `scales` package), but its not what `scale` does!